# enable and disable broadcast receiver on button click

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i want to enable and disable broadcast receiver for boot complete on button click.. The receiver shouldn't respond until button is clicked once. i did see some similar questions but non of the answers worked.. please help...

i tried this code but didn't work..

```
PackageManager pm  = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("mypackage", ".receivername");
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: Kindly accept/up Vote the answer if you have got your solution :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            PackageManager pm  = Re_editActivity.this.getPackageManager();
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(currentActivity.this, name_of_your_receiver.class);
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PackageManager pm  = Re_editActivity.this.getPackageManager();
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(currentActivity.this, name_of_your_receiver.class);
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

here button1 is used to activate broadcast receiver and button2 to deactivate it
 Also u need to register your broadcast receiver in manifest file and set

```
<receiver android:name="name_of_your_receiver" android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter >                
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>                
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample Code where you can **register** your receiver inside **onCreate** Method and **onDestroy** Method you **unregister** it,

```
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Overrride
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

      // your oncreate code

      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
      filter.addAction("SOME_ACTION");
      filter.addAction("SOME_OTHER_ACTION");

      receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          //do something based on the intent's action
        }
      }

      registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

**Remember** to run this in the **onDestroy** method:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  unregisterReceiver(receiver); //unregisterReceiver can be anywhere based on your requirement
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort.. i tried this on button click but doesnt work...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to use it this way:

```
public static void setAppComponentEnabled(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final Class<?> componentClass, final boolean enable) {
    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    final int enableFlag = enable ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(context, componentClass), enableFlag, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
YourBroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new YourBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();  //Filter for your receiver...
filter.addAction(your action goes here...);
registerReceiver(mReceiver , filter); **// Register**

unregisterReceiver(mReceiver );  **// Unregister**
```